# What is Data Type of ActivityDate (Due Date) field on Task Object?

Tags: tasks, fields

On the Task's field setup page, the ActivityDate is described as `Date/Time` but when I try to assign a DateTime variable to it, then I receive this error

`t.ActivityDate = DateTime.now() //this line of code created below error`

> Illegal assignment from Datetime to Date

When I assign a Date, then no error.

`t.ActivityDate = Date.today() //This works fine`

Salesforce documentation also suggests it is a Date field.

My question is, is this a mistake on part of Salesforce or Bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: looks like this is a bug. I tried in my devbox and got the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug, DueDate Datatype itself is 'Date' not Date/Time.[image]

Comment: It seems they fixed it :)